# Preview image by its own id separately for each comment

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

In my commentary upload image system, its browse image and display it.
If I browse a image in a comment, its also display all others comment's display field.
Is it possible to display browse image only each comment separately by its own $id.

(N.B. comment field show/hide by its own $id, which is remove here for use)

This is my work http://jsfiddle.net/er9e72ww/2/

And my preview image script is:

```
//preview image
$(".repfile").change(function(){
    previewPic(this);
});

function previewPic(input) {
 if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $(".preview_rep").attr('src', e.target.result);
        $(".output_rep").show();
        $(".replycom").focus();
        $('#img').hide();
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
 }
}
```

And php upload form:

```
<div align="left" id="show_img_upload_rep" class="show_img_upload_rep" style="padding-top:5px; display:none">
<div class="upfrmrep" >
  <div class="output_rep" style="display:none;">
  <img class="preview_rep" src="" alt="No Image Found"/>
  </div>
      <form action="uploadpostimg.php" class="upload_Reply" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="file" style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;">Filename (Max 200 Kb) :  </label>
      <input type="file" name="file" class="repfile" id="'.$id.'" value=""/> 
      <img class="loading" src="loader.gif" alt="" style="margin:5px;display:none;"/>
      <input type="submit" class="upload_file" name="upload_btn" value="Upload Picture"/>
      </form>
   </div></div>
```

Now I want to use a $id for each preview like below:

php

```
//Preview want to Add '.$id.'
  <div class="output_rep'.$id.'" style="display:none;">
  <img class="preview_rep'.$id.'" src="" alt="No Image Found"/>
  </div>
```

Script that I tried( maybe wrong) not working

```
//preview image
$(".repfile").change(function(){
    var ID = $(this).attr('id').replace('','');
    previewPic(this);
});

function previewPic(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $(".preview_rep"+ID).attr('src', e.target.result);
        $(".output_rep"+ID).show();
        $(".replycom").focus();
        $('#img').hide();
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I am passing the element to the other function I can get the ID from there. No need to get the ID in your change handler.

Remove:

```
var ID = $(this).attr('id').replace('','');
```

Change:

```
$(".preview_rep"+ID).attr('src', e.target.result);
$(".output_rep"+ID).show();
```

To:

```
$(".preview_rep" + input.id).attr('src', e.target.result);
$(".output_rep" + input.id).show();
```